# How to change Microsoft Edge WebView2 mDNS behavior by calling CreateWebView2EnvironmentWithDetails?

Tags: webrtc, microsoft-edge, mdns

I'm developing WebRTC application using Microsoft Edge WebView2. I want to change the value of edge://flags/#enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns flag from 'Default' to 'Disabled'.

According to the MSDN doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2/reference/webview2.idl, the API CreateWebView2EnvironmentWithDetails has an argument additionalBrowserArguments which can change chromium flags. I've tried the following values which don't work at all.

```
WCHAR args[] = TEXT("--enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns=0");
WCHAR args[] = TEXT("--disable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns");
WCHAR args[] = TEXT("--edge-webview-switches=\"--enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns=0\"");
WCHAR args[] = TEXT("--edge-webview-switches=--enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns=0");
WCHAR args[] = TEXT("--edge-webview-switches=--disable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns");
```

The above args won't work in the API

```
CreateWebView2EnvironmentWithDetails(nullptr, nullptr, args, callback_handler);
```

I'm using Microsoft Edge with version 80.0.315.0 (Official build) canary (64-bit) on a Window 10.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to the MSDN doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2/reference/webview2.idl, the API CreateWebView2EnvironmentWithDetails has an argument additionalBrowserArguments which can change chromium flags. I've tried the following values which don't work at all.

I've tried it with [official Samples](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples) and [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). The Arguments was correctly added to the process:

[image]

The reason why it doesn't work is because there is no such switch:

Here is the [switch list](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) found at [Run Chromium with flags](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags). I searched through the list and didn't find a switch named `--enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns`.

When I enabled the flag manually through `edge://flags/#enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns` and checked it, the switch looks like this:

[image]

So the answer is clear, you should change the parameter from `--enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns` to `--enable-features=WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns`

Answer (score 1):

I found this information in documentation.

> "The switches are not guaranteed to be applied except for the first
>   WebView that starts the browser process. If parsing failed for the
>   specified switches, they will be ignored. nullptr will run browser
>   process with no flags."

Reference:

[members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2/reference/webview2.idl#members)

You can also try to provide the feedback about the issue from Edge (Chromium) browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The listed arguments also don't work in beta version. The only way to successfully disable mDNS of Edge is by changing it in edge://flags/#enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns. Using command line option like msedge.exe --edge-webview-switches="enable-webrtc-hide-local-ips-with-mdns=0" doesn't work.

Comment: As I informed you before, it can be possible that it does not work with current versions of MS Edge (chromium). It is expected that it will get fixed once it get launched officially. At present, I suggest you to provide feedback from MS Edge browser about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This code demonstrates how to use WebView2 with an anonymous proxy and to prevent WebRTC leaks.

The simplest way to kill off WebRTC leaks in WebView2 is to change the policy in the registry when your app first starts up. This can be done at LocalMachine or CurrentUser Level. CurrentUser is best. https://admx.help/?Category=EdgeChromium&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Edge::WebRtcLocalhostIpHandling

Setting the WebRtcLocalhostIpHandling registry key to disable_non_proxied_udp will prevent the IP from being leaked.

```
Dim RegKey = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\WebView2")
RegKey.SetValue("WebRtcLocalhostIpHandling", "disable_non_proxied_udp", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
```

I run the following code on form close to clean up

```
Dim RegKey = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge")
If RegKey.GetSubKeyNames.Contains("WebView2") Then RegKey.DeleteSubKey("WebView2")
```

The same code works perfectly for Edge:

```
Dim RegKey = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge")
RegKey.SetValue("WebRtcLocalhostIpHandling", "disable_non_proxied_udp", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
```

I run the following code on form close to clean up

```
Dim RegKey = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge")
If RegKey.GetValueNames.Contains("WebRtcLocalhostIpHandling") Then RegKey.DeleteValue("WebRtcLocalhostIpHandling")
```

You can also use this following code to prevent LocalIP leaks (which should be blocked by default these days) and to force WebView2 traffic through a proxy server of your choice.

```
Dim TargetURL As String = "https://proxy6.net/en/privacy"
Dim Proxy As String = "1.1.1.1:8080"
Dim WV As Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 = New Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2
WV.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Form1.Controls.Add(WV)
AddHandler WV.NavigationCompleted, AddressOf WV_NavigationCompleted
Dim Options As CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions = New CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions()
' Force the traffic through a proxy server?
If Proxy <> "" Then Options.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--proxy-server=" & Proxy
' Prevent WebRTC leaks of local IP addresses 
Options.AdditionalBrowserArguments &= " --enable-features=WebRtcHideLocalIpsWithMdns"
Dim env As CoreWebView2Environment = Await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Nothing, Nothing, Options)
Await WV.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env)
' Any javascript we want to inject / run for every page?
Await WV.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync("//Javascript to add / run each time a page is created ")
WV.Source = New Uri(TargetURL, UriKind.Absolute)
```